# Adding card to listview flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to add Card widget each ListTile. Where do I insert it.
Here's a snippet from my whole code.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<List>(
        stream: _streamController.stream,
        builder: 
        (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        
          if (snapshot.hasData)
            return ListView(
              children: [
                for (Map document in snapshot.data)
             ListTile(
                contentPadding:
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
                leading: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      border: new Border(
                          right: new BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.cyan))),
                  child: Icon(Icons.notifications, color: Colors.cyan),
                  ),
                    title: Text("Announcement"
                 ),
                    subtitle:  (document['type']=="Announcement")?Text("Management posted new announcement."):Text('None'),
               trailing:
               Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right, color: Colors.cyan, size: 30.0),
                onTap: () {
                },
                  ),
               
              ],
            );
          return new CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

I wanna add Card widget for the layouting. Please help.
Any answers would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean the whole `ListView` should be in a `Card` widget?

Comment: @R.Shpd each `ListTile`, should be in `Card` widget

Answer (score 0):

Basically any widget can be a Card, however depending on your requirement either the 'title' or 'subtitle' could be a Card. I edited your code and added Card to subtitle with following results.

[image]

```
    ListTile(
        contentPadding:
            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
        leading: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            border: new Border(
              right: new BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
          child: Icon(Icons.notifications, color: Colors.black),
        ),
        tileColor: Colors.grey,
        title: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
          child: Text(
            "ANNOUCEMENT",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
        subtitle: Card(
          child: Container(
            height: 50,
            child: Text("Management posted new announcement."),
          ),
        ),
        trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
            color: Colors.black, size: 30.0),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `ListTile` in `Card` widget like this:

```
    ListView(
          children: [
            for (Map document in snapshot.data)
         Card(
           child: ListTile(
              contentPadding:
              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
              leading: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    border: new Border(
                        right: new BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.cyan))),
                    child: Icon(Icons.notifications, color: Colors.cyan),
                   ),
                  title: Text("Announcement"),
                  subtitle:  (document['type']=="Announcement")?Text("Managementposted 
                         new announcement."):Text('None'),                
                    trailing:
                    Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right, color: Colors.cyan, size: 30.0),
              onTap: () {},
                ),
         ),
           
          ],
        )
```